# Safari Inspector CSS Media Query Selectors Show as [object Object]

Tags: safari, media-queries, inspector

It's just as the title says, all CSS selectors which are inside of media queries are showing in the inspector as [object Object]. Has anyone else run into this? Does anyone have any idea how I can force it to show the actual selectors being used? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. All selectors. Running a webview in Cordova on an iPhone 6+, iOS 9.0.1. Stylesheets generated with Stylus. 
Running the identical css and html in OSX Safari works fine.

UPDATE-- Fixed by Safari 9.0

Comment: Indeed, this does seem to have been fixed in Safari 9.0. In general this is a pretty nice update to the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

We’ve had a similar problem when using the `keyframes` mixin of LESS HAT. CSS selectors appeared as `[object Object]` in the web inspector when using mobile Safari on iOS9.

LESS CSS with LESS HAT generated stylesheets which stopped working after the iOS / Safari update. LESS HAT’s GitHub [Issue #156](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/issues/156) addresses and [Pull Request #157](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/pull/157) fixed these problems.

If you are not using LESS HAT or the like, it might just be a problem with a faulty CSS rule. In our case Safari’s console showed a warning: `Invalid CSS property declaration […]`

Comment: Yeah I've dealt with similar issues in the past where scss mixins were causing it but this time it's pure css. I've run my css file through a linter and I'm not seeing any syntax errors and this is now happening across multiple sites.

Comment: I'm also running into this, although in my case, it's happening for all selectors, not just ones inside media queries. I have 0 console errors and warnings. This is obviously makes debugging rather difficult. I'm running iOS 9.0.1 FWIW.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's gotten worse or if I wasn't seeing the full scope of the issue originally but it's definitely not just happening on media queries for me anymore. On one of my sites the css seems to fail up to line 75 but then the next style on line 82 is reading out properly... The fact that earlier lines are broken and later lines are working is truly strange.